# Please I want to prefix my WP posts title according to each category

Tags: posts, customization, title, wp-title

What i mean is that.

My categories are:

Music.
Video
Etc...

So i want post title per category to be like this.

Post in music = should be "Download **Music**: `wp_title()`"

Post in video = should be "Download **Video**: `wp_title()`

Answer (score 0):

You have already mentioned the function [`wp_title()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_title/). Right before outputting the title, it passes its value through the filter `wp_title`, which can be used here to prepend with additional information.

```
add_filter('wp_title', 'WPSE_20181106_prepend_title', 10, 3);
function WPSE_20181106_prepend_title($title, $sep, $seplocation) {
    // not a single post
    if (!is_singular('post')) {
        return $title;
    }

    // IDs of categories that should prepend the title
    $prepend_categories = [15, 35];

    // get all categories of post
    $categories = get_the_category();
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        // found category
        if (in_array($category->term_id, $prepend_categories)) {
            // return new format, using __() so it is translateable
            return sprintf('%s %s: %s',
                __('Download', 'lang-slug'),
                $category->name,
                $title
            );
        }
    }
    // category not found, return default
    return $title;
}
```